# Python test for a url and image type

Tags: python, syntax

In the following code how to test for if the type is url or if the type is an image

```
for dictionaries in d_dict:
  type  = dictionaries.get('type')
  if (type starts with http or https):
    logging.debug("type is url")
  else if type ends with .jpg or .png or .gif
    logging.debug("type is image")
  else:
     logging.debug("invalid type")
```

Comment: why is this tagged `pythonic`? you seem to have need help with syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re

r_url = re.compile(r"^https?:")
r_image = re.compile(r".*\.(jpg|png|gif)$")

for dictionaries in d_dict:
  type  = dictionaries.get('type')
  if r_url.match(type):
    logging.debug("type is url")
  else if r_image.match(type)
    logging.debug("type is image")
  else:
     logging.debug("invalid type")
```

Two remarks: `type` is a builtin, and images could be loaded from an URL too.

Comment: @Rajeev: you sure will, and when it won't work you'll ask for help on SO.

Comment: @silent ghost:thanks but again i will deal with it.I just needed a clue to start of with.

Comment: @rajeev: and the code you had is not enough? Do you know enough of python to write what you have in syntactically-correct Python?

Comment: @silent ghost:No offense,but i thought the code was good enough for my requirements.please let me know.if anything wrong in the above .I would surely appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't work. `.match` looks at the front of the string, and `.gif` will never match there. Also the `.` should be escaped. I've no idea why you'd go for regex here, when Python offers perfectly good `string.startswith(x)` and `.endswith(y)` methods.

Comment: r".(jpg|png|gif)$" --> this regex is not completely correct:
something like r".*\.(jpg|png|gif)$" must be used instead.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot tell what type a resource is purely from its URL. It is perfectly valid to have an GIF file at a URL without a `.gif` file extension, or with a misleading file extension like `.txt`. In fact it is quite likely, now that URL-rewriting is popular, that you'll get image URLs with no file extension at all.

It is the `Content-Type` HTTP response header that governs what type a resource on the web is, so the only way you can find out for sure is to fetch the resource and see what response you get. You can do this by looking at the headers returned by `urllib.urlopen(url).headers`, but that actually fetches the file itself. For efficiency you may prefer to make HEAD request that doesn't transfer the whole file:

```
import urllib2
class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def get_method(self):
        return 'HEAD'

response= urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url))
maintype= response.headers['Content-Type'].split(';')[0].lower()
if maintype not in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'):
    logging.debug('invalid type')
```

If you must try to sniff type based on the file extension in a URL path part (eg because you don't have a net connection), you should parse the URL with [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) first to remove any `?query` or `#fragment` part, so that `http://www.example.com/image.png?blah=blah&foo=.txt` doesn't confuse it. Also you should consider using [`mimetypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) to map the filename to a Content-Type, so you can take advantage of its knowledge of file extensions:

```
import urlparse, mimetypes

maintype= mimetypes.guess_type(urlparse.urlparse(url).path)[0]
if maintype not in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'):
    logging.debug('invalid type')
```

(eg. so that alternative extensions are also allowed. You should at the very least allow `.jpeg` for `image/jpeg` files, as well as the mutant three-letter Windows variant `.jpg`.)

Comment: how would you do this for python 3?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote based on previous comments a python script, which first checks per HEAD request for the content_type and if this fails for the mimetype.
Hope this helps.

```
    import mimetypes
    import urllib2


    class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
        def get_method(self):
            return 'HEAD'

    def get_contenttype(image_url):
        try:
            response= urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(image_url))
            maintype= response.headers['Content-Type'].split(';')[0].lower()
            return maintype
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            print(e)
            return None

    def get_mimetype(image_url):
        (mimetype, encoding) =  mimetypes.guess_type(image_url)
        return mimetype

    def get_extension_from_type(type_string):
        if type(type_string) == str or type(type_string) == unicode:
            temp = type_string.split('/')
            if len(temp) >= 2:
                return temp[1]
            elif len(temp) >= 1:
                return temp[0]
            else:
                return None

    def get_type(image_url):
        valid_types = ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg')
        content_type = get_contenttype(image_url)
        if content_type in valid_types:
            return get_extension_from_type(content_type)
        mimetypes = get_mimetype(image_url)
        if mimetypes in valid_types:
            return get_extension_from_type(mimetypes)
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to guess the type of a resource from its URL, then I suggest you use the [mimetypes](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) library.  Realize, however, that you can really only make an educated guess this way.

As bobince suggests, you could also make a HEAD request and use the Content-Type header.  This, however, assumes that the server is configured (or, in the case of a web application, programmed) to return the correct Content-Type.  It might not be.

So, the only way to *really* tell is to download the file and use something like [libmagic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libmagic) (although it is conceivable even that could fail).  If you decide this degree of accuracy is necessary, you might be interested in this [python binding for libmagic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/0.1).