# how to find if a s3 url is image or not in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I have bunch of images in S3

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/image_datasets/im01.jpg
```

Although in this example it is an image, the url may or may not be an image.

From a python 3 client, I need to figure out if this url is an image or not. I was thinking if there is a way to read only the Content-type of that http request url similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702331/python-test-for-a-url-and-image-type) - in python 3.

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would ordinarily make a HEAD request and check the Content-Type in the response. For images, the content type will start with `image/`.

```
import requests
def is_image(uri):
    resp = requests.head(uri)
    return resp.headers.get('content-type', '').startswith('image/')
```

You want to make a HEAD request, not a GET request, because you don't want to download the image. You just want some metadata. That’s what HEAD is for.

This is not specific to S3 but works with any HTTP URI which is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking if there is a way to read only the **Content-type** of that http request url

Yes, you can use this kind of code (thanks to requests library) to read the Content-Type of the HTTP response:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('http://url/to/img.jpg')
print r.headers['Content-Type']
```

You will get a result like `image/jpeg`.

**EDIT**: as Dietrich Epp mentionned, better to use HEAD request instead of GET.

Comment: You should not use `requests.get` if you only need the headers. You should be using `requests.head`, which makes a HEAD request.